# CFFI: keep cdata alive as long as buffer is referencing it

Tags: python, python-cffi, cffi

I have wrapped C library via CFFI and I want my Python objects to provide buffer interface to underlying C data. I have something like this:

```
class Series(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._series = ffi.gc(new_series(), free_series)
        self.rawdata = ffi.buffer(self._series.data, self._series.len)
```

The problem is that `self.rawdata` doesn't keep `self._series` alive. I get segfault if I do something like:

```
var = Series()
var = series.rawdata # Series object is garbage collected and free_series is called
print(bytes(var)) # at this point memory pointed by buffer is deallocated
```

I tried to workaround this by using `ffi.gc` to object returned by `ffi.buffer`, but sadly the type returned by `ffi.buffer` is not accepted.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but did you try `raw=ffi.buffer(ffi.gc(_series.data, myfree), _series.len)`?  It might work because `raw=ffi.buffer(x, len)` will keep the object `x` as long as `raw` is alive.  `myfree` cannot be just the `free_series` function, though, but maybe something like `lambda x: free_series(self._series)`.

Comment: @ArminRingo Thank you, it works. Seems obvious in retrospect :)